# Trying to troubleshoot "out of scope" compiling error: CodeBlocks, Linux Fedora

Tags: c++, linux, scope, compiler-errors, codeblocks

Please help me understand the source of this error - I'm unable to tell if it's the code or the settings for the IDE. Although "out of scope" questions are very common I have searched the answers but nothing found that helps.

I'm following a C++ course online at SoloLearn. Further to their suggestion I've downloaded and set up Codeblocks in Linux so that I can follow the course by writing the code and compiling it inside the IDE rather than simply online via their browser window. Everything's been fine until now ;0/

So I'm following a lesson on "composition" and (again following their suggestions) have broken down their code and created separate files to define constructors/classes. However, despite believing I'm doing everything correctly, I keep getting this one "out of scope" error.

Here is their code, written on a single page. If I copy and paste into the IDE as a single file it compiles successfully, and my chosen terminal window pops up with the expected output:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Birthday {
public:
    Birthday(int m, int d, int y)
    : month(m), day(d), year(y)
    {  }
    void printDate()
    {
        cout<<month<<"/"<<day <<"/"<<year<<endl;
    }
private:
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

class Person {
public:
    Person(string n, Birthday b)
    : name(n), bd(b)
    {  }
    void printInfo()
    {
        cout << name << endl;
        bd.printDate();
    }
private:
    string name;
    Birthday bd;
};

int main() {
Birthday bd(2, 21, 1985);
Person p("David", bd);
p.printInfo();
}
```

What I'm now doing is removing the first constructor definition into separate `.h` and `.cpp` files, like so:

```
#ifndef BIRTHDAY_H
#define BIRTHDAY_H


class Birthday
{
public:
    Birthday(int  m, int d, int y);
    void printDate();

private:
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

#endif // BIRTHDAY_H
```

and

```
#include "Birthday.h"
using namespace std;

Birthday::Birthday(int m, int d, int y)
: month(m), day(d), year(y)
{ }

void printDate()
    {
        cout<<month<<"/"<<day <<"/"<<year<<endl;
    }
```

Whatever I do, I've cleaned, re-run the project files. I've deleted and recreated them. I've rebooted. But every time I try building, I get the following:

- error: cout was not declared in this scope
- error: month was not declared in this scope
- error: day was not declared in this scope
- error: year was not declared in this scope.

If the code had never worked at all I'd be looking harder at my tools, but why is it that copying it into separate files gives me this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `iostream` in either Birthday.cpp or Birthday.h. Second, the definition of `printDate` needs to be scoped to the class: `Birthday::printdate`.

Comment: very helpful - thanks. Because I'm trying to learn rather than simply ask for an answer (and I don't yet know how to scope printDate correctly), can you please explain how:
it is within scope as originally written i.e. does not need 'additional' scope,
and, more importantly,
how did moving it into a separate file but with all the code otherwise intact, move it out of scope?

Comment: @whatshisface With member function definitions you have to tell the compiler they are part of the class. Otherwise they are just normal C-style functions. That's what the `::` operator does along with putting the class name in front of it. It worked in your first example because you put the definition inside the class declaration.

Comment: Ah!!! clarity! Thanks :0)
I thought it would be important to properly understand this. A bit of trial and error, but I found the answer. Wouldn't have done it without such helpful prompting :0)